# Android - Simple code to enable notification bar

Tags: android

I have an Android device where the default is for the Notification bar to be off so you cannot drag it down. I want to write a simple program that turns the notification bar back on so you can drag it down to view the notifications. If someone could show me the code to do that I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 5):

First ,you must Have a look at [**Android SDK - Creating Status Bar Notifications**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)  page.

```
NotificationManager manger = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon,
                "Notification text that will be shown on status bar.", System
                        .currentTimeMillis());

        // The PendingIntent will launch activity if the user selects this
        // notification
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
                REQUEST_CODE, new Intent(this, MyActivity.class), 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "Content Title", "Content text",
                contentIntent);
        manger.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

For having an example, refer this [**anddev.org page**](http://www.anddev.org/show_notification_in_statusbar-t1019.html) .

Also having a look at this  [**Example**](http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/01/android-basics-notifications/) .

Comment: ah, so you need an icon!? it wasn't showing up when i put "0" for icon resrouce, I assumed that would work. I got no error message though, but nothing happened ... not impressive.

Answer (score 0):

On what device is "the default is for the Notification bar to be off"?  If an app can't rely on being able to post a notification such that the user can see and respond to it without the app doing anything additional, that is not a compatible device and the manufacturer needs to fix it.